# Dependency deployment using eclipse

Tags: deployment

I'm trying to deploy a custom object using eclipse but  throwing an error since it is missing a custom button which is a visualforce page. Is there a way where I can push the multiple components like objects,pages and related classes in a single push? I can't push the page since I use a Standard Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy any number of items up to the maximum deployment limit (5,000 items). To do so, simply follow these steps:

## Refresh The Metadata

Since overwrites do not happen automatically, I recommend using Force.com > Refresh from server before you get started. You may also want to delete any components that are only saved locally (e.g. the object file that failed to deploy), choosing "No" if you're prompted to delete the files from the server as well (this will only cause errors at best, and waste your time).

## Turn Off Build Automatically

Go to the Project menu and disable "Build Automatically." This means that you can set up the files the way you want without triggering a build (which is why the failures happen if the project files aren't built correctly).

## Modify All Related Files

Update or create all the necessary files in your workspace. For files that you left as local files that need to be redeployed, open the file, type in a space, delete that space, then save it. This updates the Last Modified flag, which will include the file in the build.

## Perform a Build

Click on Project > Build or turn Build Automatically back on. At this point, the Force.com IDE will find all modified files in the project and build a deployment that includes all the components.

Comment: I think, no need to turn off build automatically option. We always need to turn it on. User modify related files and when try to save it save on server. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj Normally, yes, if you want to deploy one edit at a time. If you want to deploy multiple changes in bulk, turning off the Build Automatically feature prevents deployment errors by allowing us to set up multiple files across multiple folders before deploying.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I changed apex class, VF page and object in parallel and when I saved (Ctrl+Shift+S) then all saved.All files are in different folder. Is it a different scenario?

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj That can also work, but I sometimes find it slows down my system worse than if I just build afterwards. Besides, by not using automatic builds, it lets me open, save, re-save, and close files as I need. That said, if there's only a half-dozen files or so you need open, then Ctrl-Shift-S (or using the Save All toolbar icon/menu) also works.